# Can I bring up a network interface even when its disconnected?

Tags: networking, server, ethernet

I'm running Ubuntu Server 20.04.

I have python3 http server running.  I can connect to the eth port and access it at 192.168.1.12.

If I disconnect the ethernet and then remote access the system via wifi (direct hotspot) instead, I can't access it at 192.168.1.12, but I can at my configured wifi address of 192.168.2.12.

Next, if I connect ethernet, but still access the unit via the wifi hotspot, I can now reach it at 192.168.1.12.

So I'm wondering how I can keep that accessibility even without the ethernet connected.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: What are you connecting with (the client) ?  If its a windows desktop or laptop, I have an answer

Comment: The clients will be windows laptops, preferably over wifi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure Windows PCs to use multiple IP addresses to connect to multiple DHCP servers. This can be achieved on Windows as follows -

Assuming that you leave your PC connected by ethernet. So you can access the server at **192.168.1.12**

1. Click on the Network Icon on Taskbar
2. Click on **Change Adapter Options**
3. Click on the ethernet card (its the one that hasn't got Not Connected, TAP, VPN, TeamViewer etc beside it)
4. Click on <kbd>Properties</kbd> button
5. Select **Internet Protocol Version 4**
6. Click on <kbd>Properties</kbd> button
7. You can leave **Obtain an IP address automatically** or set up a preferred IP Address.  This is for your ethernet connection.
8. Click on <kbd>Advanced</kbd> button
9. Under **IP addresses**, Click on <kbd>Add</kbd> button
10. Enter  **198.168.2.xxx** and subnet of **255.255.255.0**
11. Click on <kbd>Add</kbd> button
12. Keep pressing <kbd>Ok</kbd> as you exit out.

Where **xxx** is any valid, unique IP address that you want your laptop.  Now you are connected to two subnets. 192.168.1.xxx and 192.168.2.xxx

Swap step 10 to **192.168.1.xxx** if your laptop would normally connect to WIFI.

If you dont want to select an IP address, set up the gateway instead. The image shows both values filled in.  I have a similar setup.

[image: Setup]

### Last Note

I have the metric set as auto, Windows should sort it out as Wifi is slower than ethernet.  If you need to steer the traffic then read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/automatic-metric-for-ipv4-routes)

Comment: How is this related to the question?

Comment: Perhaps you are reading the question differently to me.  I am reading it as the OP wanting to connect to two subnets at the same time.

Comment: I am reading that OP has an Ubuntu Server, not a Windows PC.

Comment: Before answering, I asked him.  See comments.  he has windows laptops (clients).

Comment: @Pilot6 - If you think that I have the wrong end of the stick, I can delete my answer.

Comment: Thanks Rohit, that would certainly be an acceptable answer. Only issue is that I won't necessarily be able to make the changes for anyone he needs to access this, and they actually often run a batch file that's sets the IP to common addresses we need to access. I actually went ahead and just changed the WiFi IP to a different common IP we use to make it simpler. Thank your for your help though!